# twitter bootstrap modal not really modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there an option in the bootstrap modal to make it stay modal even if the user clicks away from the modal?  The modal dialog hides when the user click outside the dialog.  I would like it to stay modal until the user clicks the close button.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Specify a static backdrop option

```
$("#yourModal").modal({"backdrop": "static"});
```

Answer (score 15):

Add the attribute `data-backdrop="static"` to your modal div like so:

```
<div id="someModal" class="modal hide" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/SnhUg/1/

```
$("#example").modal({backdrop:false});
```